# Can kafkajs consume messages with different schemas from the same topic using the same consumer?

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-schema-registry, kafkajs

A topic has messages with [different schemas using `RecordNameStrategy`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#overview).

Can a consumer implemented with kafkajs (version 3.0.1) consume in the same batch those messages and parse them?

Actually, from the [source code](https://github.com/kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry/blob/v3.0.1/src/SchemaRegistry.ts#L203) seems it can, since it gets the schema from the embedded id in the message itself:

```js
  public async decode(buffer: Buffer): Promise<any> {
    if (!Buffer.isBuffer(buffer)) {
      throw new ConfluentSchemaRegistryArgumentError('Invalid buffer')
    }

    const { magicByte, registryId, payload } = decode(buffer)
    if (Buffer.compare(MAGIC_BYTE, magicByte) !== 0) {
      throw new ConfluentSchemaRegistryArgumentError(
        `Message encoded with magic byte ${JSON.stringify(magicByte)}, expected ${JSON.stringify(
          MAGIC_BYTE,
        )}`,
      )
    }

    const schema = await this.getSchema(registryId)
    return schema.fromBuffer(payload)
  }
```

But we are getting this weird error:

```
error in message number 99 {"message":"truncated buffer","stack":"Error: truncated buffer
    at RecordType.Type.fromBuffer (/my-platform/backend/node_modules/avsc/lib/types.js:601:11)
    at SchemaRegistry.decode (/my-platform/backend/node_modules/@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry/dist/SchemaRegistry.js:159:29)"}
```